# Все-ли правильно я делаю с активностями? В андроид приложении

Tags: java, android, activity

Делаю простое приложение на Android, что-то типа тренировки счета, я новичок, поэтому возник вопрос. Есть приложение, на главном экране есть 2 кнопки: начать, правила. Кнопка Начать перекидывает во вторую активность, где уже необходимо выбрать тип задания. В этой активности есть 3 кнопки (тренировать +,-,*) которые соответсвенно также перекидывают на следующие активности. Вопрос, все ли я делаю правильно с точки зрения активностей ? Всего в приложении получается 5-7 активностей.

Comment: Может как-то можно заменить 3 активности с самими примерами на одну?

Comment: Для первого приложения норм иметь активити на каждый экран (речь ведь о приложении для смартфона?). Это старый и рабочий подход. А более современный вот: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте использовал фрагменты. Можете почитать тут [тут все подробно описано](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments)

Comment: вместо кнопок лучше навигацию используйте (можете сверху или снизу, или как вам удобно) позволяя вам разделить пользовательский интерфейс на отдельные части

Comment: С фрагментами не все опытные разработчики умеют без проблем обходиться, так что это еще тот ящик пандоры.